# Moving cell to the top of the UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITable with items filled in from a NSMutableArray. I want to know how to move the cell to the top when the cell is selected.?

I know this has to do with

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

can some1 help how to go about it. ?code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to be careful with type of UI design. Will the user understand why the table suddenly reordered itself? Will you animate the row move so the user can see the row move to the top? What does moving to the top signify?

Answer (score 1):

Replace first array element with selected array element on row select and then call `[tableviewController.tableview reloadData];`

Comment: @dig: Nice.. you stole it from my mouth!

Comment: @dig how to interchange elements in the array?

Comment: `[array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 with Object:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: @dig this does not interchange. The object at 0 is overwritten by the selected object

Comment: @dig i used exchangeObjectATIndex method :)

Comment: @dig unfortunately, I donot want to swap the objects. I want the object alone to be moved to the top position above all the objects.

Comment: Take a look at this post http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/11/15/moving-objects-within-an-nsmutablearray/